# Is sharing database with multiple serverless functions good practice?

Tags: aws-lambda, microservices, serverless

Is sharing database with multiple serverless functions good practice?

Like in a CRUD application, normally the Create, Update, Delete and Read are different operations sharing the same database. If we migrate that idea on serverless, is that still ideal? All of those operations accessing the same database.

My hesitation comes from the idea of sharing databases between different microservices. Since that increases coupling and makes things more fragile.

Comment: This seems to require opinion-based answers, with "it depends" being the default.  How about listing a concrete example?  "Submit Order" and "Lookup Order" services might need to share for example.

Comment: @DaveS In your "Submit/Lookup Order" example, it would seem like a good idea to share. But how do you see it affecting the maintainability of the code, since they rely on the same table, and changing that table structure would potentially hit both those independent functions. Would you say that's just a con that we live with?

Comment: How would you suggest splitting the data across multiple databases if the separate functions each need to perform one of the CRUD operations on a single record? How would a function creating records in the database, and another function reading, deleting or updating those records work if those functions aren't connected to the same database? It would make sense to split your databases across different microservices that perform different business roles, but to split your database up based on create vs update vs read vs delete doesn't sound like it would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this question is dependent on the circumstances of both the database and the operations.

These concerns can be boiled down to the following characteristics of the database:

- Can it handle **concurrency**? This is the number one reason that can stop a network of serverless functions from operating on the database. For example, S3 buckets cannot handle concurrency, so a workaround such as firehose or an SQS would need to be implemented in order for multiple lambdas to operate simultaneously. DynamoDB, on the other hand, can handle concurrency with no problem.
- Is it a **transactional** or **analytical** database? This would limit how fast reads vs. writes take place, and if they're too slow, your lambdas will get exponentially slower. This means that if, for example, writes are slow, then they should be done in large batches- not in small increments from multiple instances.
- What are its **limitations** for operation frequency? There can be limitations from both sides of the equation. Lambdas on default have a maximum concurrency of 1000 if they all exist in the same region. Databases often also have limitations for how many operations can take place at the same time.

In most cases, the first two bullets are most important, since limitations normally are not reached except for a few rare cases.

Comment: Good points.
In a code maintainability/fragility perspective, would you say sharing databases is something that should be avoided? Or is it something viewed as inevitable and is OK, assuming the functions sharing it is really related?

Comment: It is always possible to build a robust flow that involves sharing databases, it just may cost you $$. For example, if the arriving data needs to be caught individually (say from SNS), and you want to use cheap lambdas, that means accessing the db from multiple instances, and you'll want a transactional db and a db/flow that handles concurrency. Alternatively, you could avoid shared access and use an EC2 instance in place of the lambdas (and use batching). But that EC2 could cost you too. So it all depends on what your priorities are (I personally care a lot about cost).

Comment: Thanks for explanation , Just out of curiosity can you please elaborate more "S3 buckets cannot handle concurrency" ?

Comment: I meant "cannot handle concurrent reads/writes"- S3 buckets are unable to exhibit a steady state of data in this situation